# Bell shaped percentile curve in R

Tags: r

I have a variable which has scores of the students. I am looking for the best possible way to plot the percentiles of the score. To give a glimpse of my data,

```
[1] 26 30 27 28 27 27 29 28  3 12 27 24 29 25 26 30 25 27 28 27 25 14 30 28 24 28 27
  [28] 19 18 25 28 24 24  6 20 28 28 27 22 27 19 22 21 20 30 29 26 30 28 29 28 29 25 25
  [55] 27 26 20 26 10 21 20 16 24 24 26 27 28 27 29 29 27 23 20 18 19 26 21 25 17 22 28
  [82] 26 27 27 25 26 25 29 29 28 25 22 30 29 28 28 25 29 30 27 28 28 30 28 29 29 30 29
 [109] 27 27 28 24 25 15 20 25 24 25 28 26 27 21 18 24 24 23 30 23 28 22 29 26 29 25 29
 [136] 20 25 28 12 16 23 13 17 12 17 26 13 26 28 26 25 27 21 30 30 30 27 20 24 21 28 26
 [163] 22 21 26 29 28 24 30 22 21 25 26 28 26 23 27 25 24 27 15 21 13 28 30 29 28 27 23
 [190] 27 23 28 29 18 27 23 24 28 30 30 30 29 18 24 21 17 16 12 28 22 23 26 21 12 20 20
 [217] 26 28 27 27 30 26 29 27 24 23 27 26 14 23 16 15 26 28 27 27 25 29 15 23 22 29 26
 [244] 20 20 21 21 24 24 20 25 23 22 24 22 26 28 28 27 24 28 28 27 27 27 21 23 21 24 28
 [271] 25 23 19 21 20 21 23
```

For reproducible purposes, I have used the following code,

```
x <- seq(0,50,length=100)
quantile(x,c(.10,.20,.30,.40,.50,.60,.70,.80,.90,1)) 

10%  20%  30%  40%  50%  60%  70%  80%  90% 100% 
   5   10   15   20   25   30   35   40   45   50
```

I tried `plot(quantile(x,c(.10,.20,.30,.40,.50,.60,.70,.80,.90,1)))` but the plot is not showing the ideal way. I am looking like a normal distribution bell curved which would show the percentages like below,

[image]

For doing this I thought I should convert the variable to normal distributed one and used the following,

```
 y <- dnorm(x)
plot(x,y,type="l")
```

and got the following output,

[image]

```
> z <- scale(x)
> y <- dnorm(z)
> plot(z,y, type= "l")
```

[image]

Comment: `x <- seq(-3,3,0.01); y <- dnorm(x); plot(x,y, type='l');`

Comment: @Barranka I tried this already. For my output, I am getting the above output only. Can you please check into it?

Comment: You clearly didn't do what Barranka suggested. His output is accurate. No idea what you actually did. But I'm guessing `z <- scale(x); y <- dorm(z); plot(z,y, type= "l")` is what you meant to do (and did incorrectly).

Comment: @ Alex I tried Barranka's code and I tried urs also. But the output I am getting is not bell shaped. Please see the updated question.

Comment: @Observer You need to plot a histogram. Try `?hist'. Also, read [The Quick-R tutorial: Density plots](http://www.statmethods.net/graphs/density.html)

Comment: I suppose you want `plot(density(x))`. Is this it?

Comment: @Molx Thanks. This one produces the curve. Can we modify it to show percentages of the spread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you're looking for something like this:

```
x <- c(26 ,30 ,27 ,28 ,27 ,27 ,29 ,28 , 3 ,12 ,27 ,24 ,29 ,25 ,26 ,30 ,25 ,27 ,28 ,27 ,25 ,14 ,30 ,28 ,24 ,28 ,27
       ,19 ,18 ,25 ,28 ,24 ,24 , 6 ,20 ,28 ,28 ,27 ,22 ,27 ,19 ,22 ,21 ,20 ,30 ,29 ,26 ,30 ,28 ,29 ,28 ,29 ,25 ,25
       ,27 ,26 ,20 ,26 ,10 ,21 ,20 ,16 ,24 ,24 ,26 ,27 ,28 ,27 ,29 ,29 ,27 ,23 ,20 ,18 ,19 ,26 ,21 ,25 ,17 ,22 ,28
       ,26 ,27 ,27 ,25 ,26 ,25 ,29 ,29 ,28 ,25 ,22 ,30 ,29 ,28 ,28 ,25 ,29 ,30 ,27 ,28 ,28 ,30 ,28 ,29 ,29 ,30 ,29
       ,27 ,27 ,28 ,24 ,25 ,15 ,20 ,25 ,24 ,25 ,28 ,26 ,27 ,21 ,18 ,24 ,24 ,23 ,30 ,23 ,28 ,22 ,29 ,26 ,29 ,25 ,29
       ,20 ,25 ,28 ,12 ,16 ,23 ,13 ,17 ,12 ,17 ,26 ,13 ,26 ,28 ,26 ,25 ,27 ,21 ,30 ,30 ,30 ,27 ,20 ,24 ,21 ,28 ,26
       ,22 ,21 ,26 ,29 ,28 ,24 ,30 ,22 ,21 ,25 ,26 ,28 ,26 ,23 ,27 ,25 ,24 ,27 ,15 ,21 ,13 ,28 ,30 ,29 ,28 ,27 ,23
       ,27 ,23 ,28 ,29 ,18 ,27 ,23 ,24 ,28 ,30 ,30 ,30 ,29 ,18 ,24 ,21 ,17 ,16 ,12 ,28 ,22 ,23 ,26 ,21 ,12 ,20 ,20
       ,26 ,28 ,27 ,27 ,30 ,26 ,29 ,27 ,24 ,23 ,27 ,26 ,14 ,23 ,16 ,15 ,26 ,28 ,27 ,27 ,25 ,29 ,15 ,23 ,22 ,29 ,26
       ,20 ,20 ,21 ,21 ,24 ,24 ,20 ,25 ,23 ,22 ,24 ,22 ,26 ,28 ,28 ,27 ,24 ,28 ,28 ,27 ,27 ,27 ,21 ,23 ,21 ,24 ,28
       ,25 ,23 ,19 ,21 ,20 ,21 ,23)

dens <- density(x)
plot(dens)
tot <- sum(dens$y)
qs <- sapply(c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75), function (i) max(which(cumsum(dens$y) <= tot*i)))
lines(x = dens$x[qs], y = dens$y[qs], type = "h")
text(x = c(20, 24, 26.6, 29.5), y = 0.02, labels = c("25%", "50%", "75%", "100%"))
```

[image]

I feel like there might be a simpler way to get the `qs` values, but this seems to work too. You can either use "25%, 50%... up to here" or just make them all 25%.

Answer (score 3):

You can make such plots easily using `ggplot2`.

```
x <- rnorm(500)
y <- dnorm(x)
df <- data.frame(x=x, y=y)
q <- quantile(df$x)

df_plot <- ggplot(df) + geom_line(aes(x,y)) 
           + scale_x_continuous(breaks= seq(-4,4,0.5))
           + annotate(geom="text", x=q, y=0, label=names(q)) 
           + theme(text = element_text(size=22))
df_plot
```

[image]

And if you want to add vertical lines:

```
df_plot2 <- ggplot(df) + geom_line(aes(x,y)) 
           + scale_x_continuous(breaks= seq(-4,4,0.5))
           + annotate(geom="text", x=q, y=0, label=names(q)) 
           + geom_vline(x=q, linetype = "longdash")
           + theme(text = element_text(size=22))
df_plot2
```

[image]

To plot standard deviations of normal distribution, use

```
q <- quantile(df$x, c(1-0.997, 1-0.95, 1-0.68,0.5,0.68,0.68,0.95,0.977))
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're not providing any real data, I can only think on random data:

```
values <- rnorm(100000, 0,1) # This should be your input, not some random data
quantile(values, seq(0,1,.1))
##          0%          10%          20%          30%          40%          50%          60%          70%          80%          90%         100% 
##-4.576700921 -1.284870700 -0.845223706 -0.526137762 -0.250516413  0.005818037  0.259989565  0.527060926  0.845323134  1.283060660  4.422621338
```

And, if you want to plot this data, you should create a histogram:

```
hist(values)
```

Comment: But I am looking for bell shaped percentile curve right? how does histogram help? I am not so used to this. So if I ask absurd question, please bear with me

Comment: @Observer - a bell shaped curve is essentially a fit around the bars of a histogram that would be produced for normal data.